# ReadOnly Rest plugin giving Authentication Exception

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-plugin

I am using `readonlyRest` plugin to secure `elastic` and `kibana` but once I added the following in my `readonlyrest.yml`, the kibana starts giving me "Authentication Exception", what could be the reason for that?

**kibana.yml**

```
elasticsearch.username: "kibana"
elasticsearch.password: "kibana123"
```

**readonlyrest.yml**

```
readonlyrest:
 enable: true
 response_if_req_forbidden: Access denied!!!

 access_control_rules:

  - name: "Accept all requests from localhost"
    type: allow
    hosts: [XXX.XX.XXX.XXX]

  - name: "::Kibana server::"
    auth_key: kibana:kibana123
    type: allow

  - name: "::Kibana user::"
    auth_key: kibana:kibana123
    type: allow
    kibana_access: rw
    indices: [".kibana*","log-*"]
```

My kibana and elastic are hosted on same server, is that the reason?

Another question: If I want to make my elastic server accessible only through a particular host then can I write that host in the first section of `access_control_rules` as mentioned in `readonlyrest.yml`?

Elastic version: 6.2.3

Log error: I didn't remember exactly but it was [ACL] Forbidden and showing false in all the three control rules.

Comment: Please be more specific about your environment (e.g elasticsearch version), also auth_key shouldn't be used in production and it would be nice if you can post the readonlyrest logs.

Comment: Thanks, updated the question, I am not going to use auth_key for production, just testing the plugin as of now.

Comment: Can you try your configuration without host restriction?

Comment: I have tried that thinking that might be the blocker for other rules but that doesn't help.

Comment: Can you post your elasticsearch configuration?

Comment: I don't have that with me as of now but I haven't changed the default one except for the host name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177701/discussion-between-aht-and-aayushi-jain).